# String split into List of Lists - Page,Line,Word

Tags: python, list, split, element

With the following string:

```
string='10 11 12Line13 14 15LinePage16 17 18Line19 20 21LinePage'
```

This will split it into Pages and Lines:

```
stringsplit=[l.split('Line') for l in string.split("Page")]
```

Result:

```
[['10 11 12', '13 14 15', ''], ['16 17 18', '19 20 21', ''], ['']]
```

How do you split the Line element (ie Words) so that each would be accessible:

`stringsplit[0][0][0]` would show `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could upgrade your list comprehension to a nested list comprehension:

```
stringsplit = [
    [l.split() for l in p.split("Line")]
    for p in string.split("Page")
]

print(stringsplit[0][0][0]) # 10
```

If you want to filter the empty lines and pages:

```
stringsplit = [
    [l.split() for l in p.split("Line") if l]
    for p in string.split("Page") if p
]
```

Comment: Went with this one - thanks so much. A very clever and elegant solution!

Comment: @jaycee Thanks. You can consider to mark the answer as accepted then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map

```py
string = "10 11 12Line13 14 15LinePage16 17 18Line19 20 21LinePage"

stringsplit = [
    list(map(lambda item: item.split(" "), l.split("Line"))) for l in string.split("Page")
]

# Output: [[['10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15'], ['']], [['16', '17', '18'], ['19', '20', '21'], ['']], [['']]]
```

But this is messy, and hard to look at. You can make another function.

```py
def split(arr: list):
    return list(map(lambda item: item.split(" "), arr))

string = "10 11 12Line13 14 15LinePage16 17 18Line19 20 21LinePage"

stringsplit = [split(l.split("Line")) for l in string.split("Page")]
```

This is also probably a lot cleaner than most of the other nested list comprehension answers, since you can tell what’s going on without counting brackets and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following list comprehension which filters out empty splits:

```
string = '10 11 12Line13 14 15LinePage16 17 18Line19 20 21LinePage'

result = [[word for word in line.split() if word]
          for page in string.split('Page') if page
          for line in page.split('Line') if line]
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
[['10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15'], ['16', '17', '18'], ['19', '20', '21']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reapply the same logic again to get the desired result.

```py
testStr = '10 11 12Line13 14 15LinePage16 17 18Line19 20 21LinePage'

ans = [[line.split(' ') for line in page.split('Line')] for page in testStr.split('Page')]

# ans[0][0][0] = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested result

```
s='10 11 12Line13 14 15LinePage16 17 18Line19 20 21LinePage'

sp=[
    [
        [n for n in l.split(' ') if n] 
        
        for l in p.split('Line') if l
    ]
    for p in s.split('Page') if p
]
# [[['10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15']], [['16', '17', '18'], ['19', '20', '21']]]
```

Flat result

```
>>> sp=[
...     n
...     for p in s.split('Page') if p
...     for l in p.split('Line') if l
...     for n in l.split(' ') if n
... ]
>>> sp
['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21']
```